# SpringBoot Test ContextConfiguration has no banner

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm writing an integration testing framework, and in my parent test class I have the following:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public abstract class IntegrationTestParent extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    ...

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan("redacted")
    public static class AutomationTestConfig {
    }
}
```

Which allows me a great deal of flexibility, however, I've noticed that my custom `banner.txt` file is no longer printed out, nor is my application.properties file (which sets `spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS` and some maven filtered application variables) being read.

In addition to some really leet figlet generated ascii art, it printed out a lot of convenient debug information about the JVM and various system and environment properties so I had a really good idea about the remote environments (a la Jenkins and Bamboo or anyone's arbitrary laptop) they were running on.

Is there a way to get this to behavior in addition to `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an intermediate solution. I will call it intermediate, because I get the behavior I want (annotation based contexts that are loadable in down stream projects where I have additional configurations and beans, etc) but I didn't use the `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` class.

I swapped it for the `SpringApplicationContextLoader`. Per the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationContextLoader.html):

> A ContextLoader that can be used to test Spring Boot applications
>   (those that normally startup using SpringApplication). Can be used to
>   test non-web features (like a repository layer) or start an
>   fully-configured embedded servlet container. Use @WebIntegrationTest
>   (or @IntegrationTest with @WebAppConfiguration) to indicate that you
>   want to use a real servlet container or @WebAppConfiguration alone to
>   use a MockServletContext.
>
> If @ActiveProfiles are provided in the test class they will be used to
>   create the application context.

Based on the first few sentences, this was essentially what I was looking for.